Can we use Salesforce Code Builder cloud platform to automate Selenium JS UI tests
I am looking to automate Selenium JS UI tests using Salesforce Code Builder, just as we would do on VS Code on our local machine. It couldnt facilitate Chrome browser installation, rather than Chromium extension running in headless mode. I need to know if Cloud-based Salesforce Code Builder could be a replica of VS Code desktop?
I researched on the matter online but no help available. AI tools giving negative information on the subject matter but without providing any source
